# perl search replace is appending not replacing

Tags: perl, cron

I have a perl script in a cron that runs every X minutes. It is suppose to find a string and replace it with a string with more data:

```
s/remote_phonebook.data.1.name =/remote_phonebook.data.1.name = Users/;
```

I would expect it to look like this:

before:

```
remote_phonebook.data.1.name =
```

after:

```
remote_phonebook.data.1.name = Users
```

the first time it runs it works fine.  However, each additional time it appends to the end of the line so 3 cron jobs later i see:

```
 remote_phonebook.data.1.name = Users Users Users
```

How can make it so if "Users" doesn't exist, add it, if it exists, ignore?

Comment: And if you have `remote_phonebook.data.1.name = foo`, would you like to replace `foo` with `Users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each one of these is a new line you could try:

```
$s =~ s/remote_phonebook\.data\.1\.name =( Users|$)/remote_phonebook.data.1.name = Users/;
```

If not, please let me know on the comments.

Comment: It's easier to do `s/\Qremote_phonebook.data.1.name =\E( Users|$)/.../`

Answer (score 1):

Provide appropriate trailing context, such as only spaces after the `=` (which won't then do anything when there is `Users` after the `=`):

```
s/remote_phonebook.data.1.name =\s*$/remote_phonebook.data.1.name = Users/;
```

or even (as suggested by [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot)):

```
s/(remote_phonebook.data.1.name =)\s*$/$1 Users/;
```

Comment: `s/(remote_phonebook.data.1.name =)\s*$/$1 Users/;`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: yup; that would shorten the line too.